# Split view controller, hide a UIView on DetailVC based on action in MasterVC

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I am struggling to complete this task.
I have a splitview controller (MasterVC, DetailVC)

MasterVC is a tableView with data inside it.
Based on a certain action (such as refreshing the table), I would like to hide a View on the DetailVC when I refresh the tableView on the MasterVC and certain conditions are met.

On MasterVC: 
I have tried the following.

```
var detailVC  = DetailVC()

@objc func refresh(_ sender: Any){

    GlobalVar.trackingArray_.removeAll()
    GlobalVar.trackingArray = []

    if self.data.count == 0 {
        GlobalVar.tableViewIsEmpty = true
        detailVC.viewToHide.isHidden = false
        detailVC.otherViewToShow.isHidden = true
    } else if self.data.count > 0 {
        GlobalVar.tableViewIsEmpty = false
        detailVC.viewToShow.isHidden = true
        detailVC.OtherViewToHide.isHidden = false
        loadRelativeData(self)
    } else{
        loadRelativeData(self)
    }
    //loadData()
    refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I keep getting a crash (fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping ) on this line -> `detailVC.viewToShow.isHidden = true`

Not sure why it fails to unwrap it as it is most certainly there. 
Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Is this operation something that cannot be done on a splitViewController?

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose `viewToShow` must be nil. Are you sure there is only one `detailVC` and it's inside the split view controller? You might be making a separate one in `var detailVC  = DetailVC()`

Comment: a split view controller by default has only one detail and one master view associated to it. And I am certain I am targeting the correct VC. There is definitely not more than 1 detailvc

Comment: Are you creating your master/detail structure in a storyboard?  (If so, `var detailVC  = DetailVC()` is wrong in a variety of ways.)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this ?

Comment: @PhillipMills if it is wrong for a variety of ways please explain ?

Comment: With a storyboard, the detail view controller is created as the view controller hierarchy is initialized.  Automatically, from a coding point of view.  In that case, the one you initialize with that statement is unrelated to what is controlling the screen.  The 2nd way it would be wrong is, even if you used it to replace the "automatic" one, a default constructor wouldn't initialize the instance variables.  Their connections to their views are built through storyboard references.

Comment: If you use Xcode to create a sample master/detail project, you will find a reference to the detail inside the master...but it's not initialized to a new object.  A reference to the automatic object is obtained by discovering it in the view hierarchy.